# Accessing Kubernetes worker node labels from the Containers/pods

Tags: azure, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

How to access Kubernetes worker node labels from the container/pod running in the cluster?
Labels are set on the worker node as the yaml output of this kubectl command launched against this Azure AKS worker node shows :

```
$ kubectl get nodes aks-agentpool-39829229-vmss000000 -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  annotations:
    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: "0"
    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-15T16:09:20Z"
  labels:
    agentpool: agentpool
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type: Standard_DS2_v2
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region: eastus
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: eastus-1
    kubernetes.azure.com/agentpool: agentpool
    kubernetes.azure.com/cluster: xxxx
    kubernetes.azure.com/mode: system
    kubernetes.azure.com/node-image-version: AKSUbuntu-1804gen2containerd-2021.10.02
    kubernetes.azure.com/os-sku: Ubuntu
    kubernetes.azure.com/role: agent
    kubernetes.azure.com/storageprofile: managed
    kubernetes.azure.com/storagetier: Premium_LRS
    kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    kubernetes.io/hostname: aks-agentpool-39829229-vmss000000
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/role: agent
    node-role.kubernetes.io/agent: ""
    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type: Standard_DS2_v2
    storageprofile: managed
    storagetier: Premium_LRS
    topology.kubernetes.io/region: eastus
    topology.kubernetes.io/zone: eastus-1
  name: aks-agentpool-39829229-vmss000000
  resourceVersion: "233717"
  selfLink: /api/v1/nodes/aks-agentpool-39829229-vmss000000
  uid: 0241eb22-4d1b-4d65-870f-fcc51dac1c70
```

Note: The pod/Container that I have is running with non-root access and it doesn't have a privileged user.

Is there a way to access these labels from the worker node itself ?

Comment: Create a ServiceAccount and with correct RBAC, then you  can access the node label with Kubernetes API

Comment: @TonyYip do you mind sharing some examples?

Answer (score 1):

In the AKS cluster,

1. Create a namespace like:

   ```
   kubectl create ns get-labels
   ```
2. Create a Service Account in the namespace like:

   ```
   kubectl create sa get-labels -n get-labels
   ```
3. Create a Clusterrole like:

   ```
   kubectl create clusterrole get-labels-clusterrole --resource=nodes --verb=get,list
   ```
4. Create a Rolebinding like:

   ```
   kubectl create clusterrolebinding get-labels-rolebinding -n get-labels --clusterrole get-labels-clusterrole --serviceaccount get-labels:get-labels
   ```
5. Run a pod in the namespace you craeted like:

   ```
   cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: get-labels
     namespace: get-labels
   spec:
     serviceAccountName: get-labels
     containers:
     - image: centos:7
       name: get-labels
       command:
       - /bin/bash
       - -c
       - tail -f /dev/null
   EOF
   ```
6. Execute a shell in the running container like:

   ```
   kubectl exec -it get-labels -n get-labels -- bash
   ```
7. Install [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool in the container:

   ```
   yum install epel-release -y && yum update -y && yum install jq -y
   ```
8. Set up shell variables:

   ```
   # API Server Address
   APISERVER=https://kubernetes.default.svc
   # Path to ServiceAccount token
   SERVICEACCOUNT=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
   # Read this Pod's namespace
   NAMESPACE=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/namespace)
   # Read the ServiceAccount bearer token
   TOKEN=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/token)
   # Reference the internal certificate authority (CA)
   CACERT=${SERVICEACCOUNT}/ca.crt
   ```
9. If you want to get a list of all nodes and their corresponding labels, then use the following command:

   ```
   curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET ${APISERVER}/api/v1/nodes | jq '.items[].metadata | {name,labels}'
   ```

   else, if you want the labels corresponding to a particular node then use:

   ```
   curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET ${APISERVER}/api/v1/nodes/<nodename> | jq '.metadata.labels'
   ```

Please replace `<nodename>` with the name of node intended.

**N.B.** You can choose to include the installation of the `jq` tool in the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) from which your container image is built and make use of [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) for the shell variables. We have used neither in this answer in order to explain the working of this method.